# setter property background doesn't change the background color in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a PerformanceMeterStyle.xaml with one property that set's the background to yellow:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:TemplateLearn.Controls">
        <Style TargetType="controls:PerformanceMeter" x:Key="PerformanceMeterStyle">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
        </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then I have PerformanceMeter.cs where my dependency property's will come in. For know it just derives from Control:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace TemplateLearn.Controls
{
    public class PerformanceMeter : Control
    {
    }
}
```

In my MainWindow.xaml i use my created control:

```
<Window x:Class="TemplateLearn.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TemplateLearn"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:TemplateLearn.Controls"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

  <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/Styles/PerformanceMeterStyle.xaml" />
  </Window.Resources>

  <controls:PerformanceMeter Style="{StaticResource PerformanceMeterStyle}"/>
</Window>
```

Why is the background color of my control not changing to the property I set in PerformanceMeterStyle.xaml?

Comment: Are you sure the resource file getting imported properly? May be you can check the 'Output' window if you are in Visual Studio for any such errors OR try defining a simple style for basic WPF control like(button/textblock) in that resource file and try applying that to corresponding control in your window.

Comment: add `controls:PerformanceMeter` C# and Template codes to the question. there may be some source of problem in your code.

Comment: You need to define a ControlTemplate which actually uses the Background property. See [Customizing the Appearance of an Existing Control by Creating a ControlTemplat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/customizing-the-appearance-of-an-existing-control).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should create control template for that as follows:

```
<Style TargetType="controls:PerformanceMeter" x:Key="PerformanceMeterStyle">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:PerformanceMeter}">
                        <Border x:Name="border"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

This might actually work, if not let me know.